# Why does the direction of this line changes when I make it longer?

Tags: javascript, math, maps, leaflet

I'm trying to draw a line on a Leaflet map given a position in WGS84 coordinates, a length, and a direction angle in degrees.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([49.41611,2.06806], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var lat = 49.41611;
var lng = 2.06806;
var deg = 220;

var len = 0.3;
deg = (deg / 360) * (Math.PI * 2);
L.polyline([
    [lat, lng],
    [lat + len * Math.cos(deg), lng + len * Math.sin(deg)]
]).addTo(map);
```

The problem is that when I change the "len" variable to something else, the visible direction of the line changes.

With "len = 0.3": [image: screenshot]

With "len = 100": [image: screenshot]

Is there some problem with my calculation method? With floating point? How can I solve that?

Comment: Longitude lines are spaced the same at the equator as at higher latitudes so you can't use the same scaling factor for both latitude and longitude numbers except at the equator.  Your equation assumes equal size latitude and longitude which is only the case at the equator.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this change in direction is the fact that earth is round.

I guess you have a more fundamental mistake earlier on, though. If `dir` is to denote the direction of the line, then you can't simply translate this into latitudes aqnd longitudes. This is because they form a grid which at small scales is almost rectangular, but is square only at the equator. The distance between meridians is `cos(lat)` times the distance between parallels. So for small distances you could do

```
L.polyline([
    [lat, lng],
    [lat + len * Math.cos(deg) * Math.cos(lat), lng + len * Math.sin(deg)]
]).addTo(map);
```

You should in particular make sure that a 45° line will indeed end up at 45° even at high latitudes.

The above is only an approximation for small scales, though. For longer lines, the curvature of the earth means that the aspect ratio of the grid varies along the path of any line. In that case, I'd suggest converting to 3d cartesian coordinates, finding the coordinates of the target point in that system, then converting back. The math would be a lot more involved in that case, though. You better search and ask (if search turns up nothing) on [the Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), which also allows for nicer typesetting of formulas.